# Rotating a shape around its center using mouse position

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create a library which allows user to edit shapes on a canvas, primarily moving, resizing, and rotating the shapes.

I have a problem with my rotating code in that the degree of rotation seems to be off by -90 degrees.

This is my code that does the rotation, in the `mouseMove` event:

```
var mousePos = e.GetPosition(this.Parent as FrameworkElement);

//gridPos is the center point of the shape object (contained within a grid control for reasons
var gridPos = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft(this) + this.ActualWidth / 2, Canvas.GetTop(this) + this.ActualHeight / 2);

//Get the angle in radians
double radians = Math.Atan2(mousePos.Y - gridPos.Y, mousePos.X - gridPos.X);

//Convert to degrees
double angle = radians * (180 / Math.PI);

//Apply rotation from centre
RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

//This is applied initially to my shape control object which has the shape as child
RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(degrees);
```

This is what I'm seeing:

[image: Shape immediately starts off by -90]

As you can see, the shape immediately rotates about -90. The red marks are drawn at `mousePos` and `gridPos`.

If I put some `Debug.WriteLine` in that, this is what results:

```
MouseX: 440.14, MouseY: 148
GridX: 443.14, GridY: 197
MouseX - GridX: -3
MouseY - GridY: -49
Radians: -1.631944489444198
Degrees: -93.50353164478446
```

I can't work out what's wrong with my logic here, although I'm pretty sure `Math.Atan2(mousePos.Y - gridPos.Y, mousePos.X - gridPos.X);` isn't giving me what I think it is...

Comment: Difficult to say for sure without an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but my guess is you're handling the mouse event inside that circle, and once it moves outside the circle you're no longer getting move events. What you need to do is respond to the mouse down event with a call to the parent's CaptureMouse() function so that it gets all subsequent mouse move events (just remember to also call ReleaseMouseCapture on the mouse up event).

Comment: Ah, I think my GIF is a bit misleading. The rotation works perfectly fine after the initial offset by -90, so mouse clicks are being correctly registered. The only problem is that the first setting of the rotation gives an angle of -90ish. I'll update my question later with more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using atan2(y, x) only works if your anchor point is to the _right of the rotation point. Code for each is as follows:

```
double radians = Math.Atan2(gridPos.Y - mousePos.Y, gridPos.X - mousePos.X); // left
double radians = Math.Atan2(mousePos.X - gridPos.X, gridPos.Y - mousePos.Y); // top
double radians = Math.Atan2(gridPos.X - mousePos.X, mousePos.Y - gridPos.Y); // bottom
double radians = Math.Atan2(mousePos.Y  - gridPos.Y, mousePos.X - gridPos.X); // right
```

Ideally though, what you should be doing is calculating the angle of the point where you initially click down, then calculate the new angle for your mousemove events, setting the rotation to be whatever the difference is between them. That's essentially what each of the 4 lines above is doing, they're just hard-coding the initial mouse down point.

Comment: Ah thank you. I needed to use `Math.Atan2(mousePos.X - gridPos.X, gridPos.Y - mousePos.Y);`.